# Convert DataSet to DataReader .NET

Tags: .net, class, dataset, datareader

I have a dataset which includes many functions and used in many other functions. But I need to use it with these lines below:

```
Using objDataReader.Dr
            While objDataReader.Dr.Read()
                Me.Item = New CVMasterItem(objDataReader.Dr)
                Me.Items.Add(Me.Item)
            End While
            objDataReader.Dr.Close()
End Using

        If objDataReader.Con IsNot Nothing Then
            If objDataReader.Con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                objDataReader.Con.Close()
                objDataReader.Con.Dispose()
            End If
        End If

        Me._totalRows = Me.Items.Count
        Return Me.Items
```

I tried to convert it to data reader as below but it doesn't work:

```
Dim objDataReader As AppCommon.AppDataReader
objDataReader = GetCVList(sortExpression).Tables(0).CreateDataReader()
```

How can I convert it to datareader rather than datatablereader?

Answer (score 0):

Declare `objDataReader` like this:

```
Dim objDataReader as IDataReader
```

You  will then be able to call its `Read` method and cycle through the rows.

The `DataTableReader` implements the `DbDataReader` class, which itself implements the `IDataReader` interface.

Links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader(v=vs.110).aspx